# Stop page life cycle execution after response.write

Tags: c#, asp.net

Its a ajax request, I couldn't use webmethod so I need to prevent rest of the page to render.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
         if (Request.Form["oper"] == "add" && x = 1)
         Response.Write((new { Status = "Message", Value = "Value need to be %100!" }).ToJson());
    }
}
```

Comment: `Response.End()` not working?

Comment: please make it an answer. I love simple answers :)

Comment: I'll give it to the answerer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @leppie said [Response.End()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end(v=vs.110).aspx)